# Powershell add header/row to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a piece of code which generates a CSV of sharenames from a filer.

Its a tab-delimited CSV and is just the sharenames, no other details are included.

I'd like to take the output:

```
010
2012 Comp
2012 Comp Plan Team
```

And replace it with this:

```
\\<filer>\010
\\<filer>\2012 Comp
\\<filer>\2012 Comp Plan Team
```

Right now I have the following:

```
$Content = import-csv C:\temp\new.txt -Delimiter "`t"
```

Can I use an Add-Member command to add in the new property/values to the array?  Or am I going about this the wrong way?

---

The comments have been great so far, thanks guys.  I forgot to add another point to this.  I was wondering how I might add another column to the csv?  Strictly for filer names.  I'm thinking of producing a massive csv of share names and filer names.  So just wanted to know how I could add that into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you've shown is the only content of the file there's no need to bother with `Import-Csv`, just use `Get-Content`:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\temp\new.txt') -replace '^', '\\<filer>\'
```

The above produces merely an array of strings. To make this a CSV with 2 columns you could do several things, for instance transform the string array into an array of objects with the same 2 properties:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\temp\new.txt') -replace '^', '\\<filer>\' |
  select @{n='Path';e={$_}}, @{n='col2';e={...}}
```

or append `,something` to the strings and convert the array to a CSV:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\temp\new.txt') -replace '^', '\\<filer>\' -replace '$', ',...' |
  ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: Just to check, because my powershell is extremely lacking, the caret is a regex expression to show the start of the line?   Or is it a powershell expression?

Comment: Correct, it's a regular expression matching the beginning of a line. The command means basically "read all lines from the file and prepend each with the given string".

Answer (score 0):

Not Import-CSV. But, you should use `Get-Content`, IMO.

```
$content = Get-Content C:\test.csv
$content | ForEach-Object { '\\<filer>\'+$_ } | Set-Content C:\new-Test.csv
```

Comment: I missed out a very important piece of this problem.